# Why is there a difference in generating a jump-table and code for a switch and equivalent if-statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, state-machine

By the below link to Compiler Explorer you get two versions of the same finite state machine: one as a switch-statement

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MORE
//#define ENTER

volatile uint8_t r = 0;
volatile uint8_t x = 0;

namespace {
    struct FSM {
        enum class State : uint8_t {Test0, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4
                        #ifdef MORE
                                    , Test5, Test6, Test7
                        #endif
                                   };
        
        inline static void process(const uint8_t b) {
            const auto oldState = mState;
            switch(mState) {
            case State::Test0:
                if (b == 0) {
                    mState = State::Test1;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test1:
                if (b == 1) {
                    mState = State::Test2;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test2:
                if (b == 2) {
                    mState = State::Test3;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test3:
                if (b == 3) {
                    mState = State::Test4;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test4:
                if (b == 4) {
#ifdef MORE
                    mState = State::Test5;
#else
                    mState = State::Test0;
#endif
                }
                break;
#ifdef MORE
            case State::Test5:
                if (b == 5) {
                    mState = State::Test6;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test6:
                if (b == 6) {
                    mState = State::Test7;
                }
                break;
            case State::Test7:
                if (b == 7) {
                    mState = State::Test0;
                }
                break;
#endif
            }
#ifdef ENTER
            if (oldState != mState) {
                switch(mState) {
                case State::Test0:
                    x = 40;
                    break;
                case State::Test1:
                    x = 41;
                    break;
                case State::Test2:
                    x = 42;
                    break;
                case State::Test3:
                    x = 43;
                    break;
                case State::Test4:
                    x = 44;
                    break;
#ifdef MORE
                case State::Test5:
                    x = 45;
                    break;
                case State::Test6:
                    x = 46;
                    break;
                case State::Test7:
                    x = 47;
                    break;
#endif
                }
            }
#endif
        }
    private:
            inline static State mState{State::Test0};
    };
    
    using fsm = FSM;
}

int main() {
    while(true) {
        const uint8_t b = r;        
        fsm::process(b);
    }
}
```

and one as equivalent if-statments.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MORE
//#define ENTER

volatile uint8_t r = 0;
volatile uint8_t x = 0;

namespace {
    struct FSM {
        enum class State : uint8_t {Test0, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4
                        #ifdef MORE
                                    , Test5, Test6, Test7
                        #endif
                                   };
        
        inline static void process(const uint8_t b) {
            const auto oldState = mState;
            if (mState == State::Test0) {
                if (b == 0) {
                    mState = State::Test1;                
                }
            }
            else {
                if (mState == State::Test1) {
                    if (b == 1) {
                        mState = State::Test2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (mState == State::Test2) {
                        if (b == 2) {
                            mState = State::Test3;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (mState == State::Test3) {
                            if (b == 3) {
                                mState = State::Test4;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (mState == State::Test4) {
                                if (b == 4) {
#ifndef MORE
                                    mState = State::Test0;                                
#else
                                    mState = State::Test5;                                
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (mState == State::Test5) {
                                    if (b == 5) {
                                        mState = State::Test6;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (mState == State::Test6) {
                                        if (b == 6) {
                                            mState = State::Test7;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (mState == State::Test7) {
                                            if (b == 7) {
                                                mState = State::Test0;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
#endif
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
#ifdef ENTER
            if (oldState != mState) {
                if (mState == State::Test1) {
                    x = 41;                    
                }
                else {
                    if (mState == State::Test2) {
                        x = 42;                        
                    }
                    else {
                        if (mState == State::Test3) {
                            x = 43;                            
                        }
                        else {
                            if (mState == State::Test4) {
                                x = 44;                                
                            }
#ifdef MORE
                            else {
                                if (mState == State::Test5) {
                                    x = 45;                                    
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (mState == State::Test6) {
                                        x = 46;                                        
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (mState == State::Test7) {
                                            x = 47;                                        
                                        }                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
#endif
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
#endif
    }
    private:
        inline static State mState{State::Test0};
    };
    
    using fsm = FSM;
}

int main() {
    while(true) {
        const uint8_t b = r;        
        fsm::process(b);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7TdEo31KE

Side note: this is a stripped down version of some tests I made to implement the finite-state-machine with template-metaprogramming, which is quite straight forward and fundamentally gives the same copy as the if-statement example by template-recursion.

First I found that gcc starts to generate a jump-table for the switch-implementation using more than 5 states, the same occurs in the if-statement example with more than 7 states.

But even with more than 7 states the code is fundamentally different: the if-statement example uses a 7-entry jump-table whereas the switch-statement example uses a jump-table with 8 entries. This is also true for x86 backend and also for clang.

My assembler skills are limited, therefore two questions arise:

1. which one is more performant?
2. can some changes to the code make the two version look the same in assembler?

Comment: I've removed the tag C because the code is not C.

Comment: switch statements probably have an extra entry for default case. The bottom line is you should use a switch if its appropriate, else use if statements. Whichever is easier to write and maintain is the correct choice. Worry about performance after you've profiled your code.

Comment: Different C++ code results in different code generation, that's pretty normal. As for performance it's probably pretty similar. To be sure mesure it. As for your second question, no chance, don't even try.

Comment: `which one is more performant?` The one that you have measured to be more performant. It often depends on the system that you run on.

Comment: Please provide source code as text in the question itself, external link may stop working which will make your question useless.

Comment: The code on the right has eight cases (Test0 - Test7) but the assembly for the code on the left has a jump table with seven entries because the code for Test0 is done before the jump table - apparently, that saves a jump to the first one.  The reason a switch statement needs a jump to the first case is that there can be code after the switch and before the first case (see Duff's Device).

Comment: But you can see here that it doesn't always pur the first if statement before the jump table: https://godbolt.org/z/b14c1Gnff   In this case both jump tables have 8 jumps and they are almost identical.

Comment: One of the factors determining the assembly language output is the properties of the `case` values.  For example, if the `case` values are sequential, the compiler can use math to determine where to branch to (often called a jump table).  For higher optimizations, if the compiler can build a branch table, it will.  Branch tables are a lot more efficient than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: The enum uses uint8_t as underlying type. So labels are strictly sequential.

Comment: You can always create a jump table, using `std::map<case_id, function_pointer>`.  This could be beneficial if there is no relationship between the `case` values.

Comment: Yes, but this disables the compiler from inlining and do some interprocedural optimization like register-allocation. I tried that already. These manually created jump-tables are worse in respect to code-size and/or performance.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah : interesting is that you get identical code with -Os. So I wonder why this does not happen in my original case